# SO question not showing all its answers

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-answers

I posted this a couple of days ago: [C++/CLI Missing MSVCR90.DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993560/c-cli-missing-msvcr90-dll)

I got my first answer from Jason Williams. I also got an answer from Hans Passant, and there several comments on that answer.

If you go to the post, however, you will see neither the answer from Hans nor any of its comments. All you see is the question and the answer from Jason.

If I go into my account settings, I can see from the question that it was last answered two days ago by Hans. If I click on [the "2 days ago" link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993560/c-cli-missing-msvcr90-dll/?lastactivity), though, I don't see the post from Hans.

There is some sort of bug in this post causing it not to display all answers and comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hans deleted his answer a day after he posted it.  Deleted answers are only visible to 10k users on SO.  Comments on deleted answers are also removed.

You'd have to ask him why he deleted it; it's not clear to me after reading it.

Comment: You can't really "ask him" on SO.

Comment: You can look in their profile for contact info (which implies to my mind that contacting them is OK withing reason) or you can find another post by that user and write a comment.

Answer (score 6):

> You have a *very* unusual version of Windows. Abandon all hope.

That was my last comment to the post.  When the normal diagnostics don't provide a lead and there is no clear avenue for developing an answer into something that might be worthwhile to somebody else some day, I delete my post.

I've been wondering lately whether it makes sense to get into these kind of one-on-one forum style questions.  Sometimes there's a nugget, like the thread I linked to, but it is very rare.  The odds of getting a helpful vote are also very slim.  Having 200 answers with 0 upvotes is enough for my taste.  Subtle hint: if you find somebody trying to be helpful, click that up-arrow to keep them interested in continuing to help you.  The idea that *somebody* on the intertubes found your effort useful is a powerful motivator.  That click doesn't cost anything.

The MSDN forums are a good place for problems like these.

Comment: +1: "Subtle hint: if you find somebody trying to be helpful, click that up-arrow to keep them interested in continuing to help you"

Comment: +1:  more voting for good answers.